# multiple search and filter data returning count of each filter in nestjs mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, search, nestjs, azure-cognitive-search

I want to filter the items in the database by their fields and also return the count of each filter.
[Example is when I select to return specific brand names I want to see the number of brand name available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n16HT.png)

Is there any search service I could use like Azure search or a way to implement this in NestJs and mongodb

This is the Database collection

```
{
  "brand": "Screaming Eagle, The Flight",
  "producer": "Screaming Eagle",
  "productionCountry": "America",
  "region": "Napa Valley",
  "appellation": "Oakville",
  "vintage": "2016",
  "grape": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
  "maturity": "25",
  "case": "3 bottles",
  "origin": "SECONDARYMARKET",
  "type": "Red"
},{
  "brand": "Joseph Phelps, Insignia",
  "producer": "Joseph Phelps",
  "productionCountry": "America",
  "region": "Napa Valley",
  "appellation": "St. Helena",
  "vintage": "2012",
  "grape": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
  "maturity": "25",
  "case": "6 bottles",
  "origin": "SECONDARYMARKET",
  "type": "Red"
},{
  "brand": "Joseph Phelps, Insignia",
  "producer": "Joseph Phelps",
  "productionCountry": "America",
  "region": "Napa Valley",
  "appellation": "St. Helena",
  "vintage": "2012",
  "grape": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
  "maturity": "25",
  "case": "6 bottles",
  "origin": "SECONDARYMARKET",
  "type": "Red"
},{
  "brand": "Continuum",
  "producer": "Continuum",
  "productionCountry": "America",
  "region": "Napa Valley",
  "appellation": "Oakville",
  "vintage": "2017",
  "grape": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
  "maturity": "26",
  "case": "6 bottles",
  "origin": "SECONDARYMARKET",
  "type": "Red"
},{
  "brand": "Continuum",
  "producer": "Continuum",
  "productionCountry": "America",
  "region": "Napa Valley",
  "appellation": "Oakville",
  "vintage": "2017",
  "grape": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
  "maturity": "26",
  "case": "6 bottles",
  "origin": "SECONDARYMARKET",
  "type": "Red"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as "facets" and it is supported by Azure Cognitive Search and MongoDB. In Azure Cognitive Search, you have to set `facetable` to true for the fields you'd like to get counts for, such as `brand` then specify in the query `"facets": ["brand"]`.

For more information Azure Search see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation

This works in MongoDb using the `$facet` aggregation operator which you can read more about here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

Comment: Okay thanks. But how can I also return filters with count of 0?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible for facets